# Sumifs returns 0 with 2 text criterias one of them is a merged cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

i have a problem with a spreadsheet where i'm trying to sumifs results from one sheet to another depedning on 2 text cretira but only one of them is returning a correct value for example
[here is the correctly working formula in the main sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkdgv.png)
the formulas of cells E372 and E373 are `=SUMIFS(E$6:E$366,$B$6:$B$366,$B372,$A$6:$A$366,$A372)` & `=SUMIFS(E$6:E$366,$B$6:$B$366,$B373,$A$6:$A$366,$A372)` in order , now the problem is when it try to sumif these results in another sheet using the same setup of merged cells as the following screenshot
[it seems to work just fine with the "promo" values but "standard" values keeps showing 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxYT0.png)
the formulas of F5 & F6 are `=SUMIFS('TA-R'!$E$372:$E$745,'TA-R'!$B$372:$B$745,'NOV-R'!$C5,'TA-R'!$A$372:$A$745,'NOV-R'!$B5)` & `=SUMIFS('TA-R'!$E$372:$E$745,'TA-R'!$B$372:$B$745,'NOV-R'!$C6,'TA-R'!$A$372:$A$745,'NOV-R'!$B5)` in order, i have no idea if the problem is with the formula but i made sure that the "standard" is the same between the 2 sheets , its also the same problem if i change the whole word with anything else

i tried to modify the formula a bit like in `=SUMIFS('TA-R'!E$372:E$745,'TA-R'!$B$372:$B$745,'NOV-R'!$C6,'TA-R'!$A$372:$A$745,@'NOV-R'!$B5:$B6)` & `=SUMIFS('TA-R'!E$372:E$745,'TA-R'!$B$372:$B$745,'NOV-R'!$C5,'TA-R'!$A$372:$A$745,@'NOV-R'!$B5:$B6)` instead of the formula mentioned above but no use , i also tried to apply the formula in a new empty sheet and still no use, the @ at the @'NOV-R'!$B5:$B6 is to prevent formuala spilling error, and the error that shows in first screenshot is because of "inconsistent formula"

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention SPILLs I reckon you're using Office 365.

You could simulate the merged cells as arrays with no blanks inside `LET()` using `TOCOL/HSTACK`:

```
=LET(a,  'NOV-R'!B5:B10,
     aa, TOCOL(HSTACK(a,a),1),
     b,  'TA-R'!A372:A377,
     bb, TOROW(HSTACK(b,b),1),
MMULT((bb=aa)*(TOROW('TA-R'!B372:B377)='NOV-R'!C5:C10),'TA-R'!C372:C377))
```

or:

```
=LET(a,  'NOV-R'!B5:B10,
     aa, TOCOL(HSTACK(a,a),1),
     b,  'TA-R'!A372:A377,
     bb, TOCOL(HSTACK(b,b),1),
XLOOKUP(aa&"|"&'NOV-R'!C5:C10,bb&"|"&'TA-R'!B372:B377,'TA-R'!C372:C377))
```

Since you altered the Range using TOCOL and HSTACK, it's no longer a range, but an array and SUMIFS does not allow arrays as range input; therefore we need the use of alternate functions, like MMULT or XLOOKUP

[image]

Comment: I'd like to really thank you a lot it totally worked out greatly, before your reply I tried a workaround by removing the merging from the TA-R and just using the same value in every 2 cells, and it worked well but didn't look as so. Thanks again.